# running ionic on android always returns 404 error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic framework, and i think since the last update whenever i run on android `ionic run android` all the urls return 404 . `ionic serve` is working correctly so is `ionic run ios`

so the issue is only on android.

- I added the Cordova whitelist plugin, changed my config.xml and index.html as follows and still facing the same issue.

in config.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.yeswegreen569862" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyAppName</name>
    <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="15+" />
    <preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
    <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
    <preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="true" />
</widget>
```

in index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

<title></title>
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/tab-main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/cat-details.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/tab-list.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/tab-details.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/tab-favorite.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/tab-add.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/tab-settings.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- google maps javascript-->
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>

        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-md5.js"></script>

        <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>


        <script src="lib/ionic-timepicker/dist/ionic-timepicker.bundle.min.js"></script>


        <script src="js/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-ios9-uiwebview.js"></script>
        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/utils.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body ng-app="myappname">

        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
          <ion-nav-back-button>
          </ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

      </body>
    </html>
```

app.js :

```
angular.module(' myappname', ['ionic', ' myappname.controllers', ' myappname.services', 'pascalprecht.translate','ngCordova','ionic-timepicker','ngIOS9UIWebViewPatch'])

.run(['$ionicPlatform', '$rootScope',' myappnameService',function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, myappnameService) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });

   $rootScope.errorCodes = {
    '5001' : 'invalid_email',
    '5002' : 'invalid_username',
    '5003' : 'invalid_password',
    '5004' : 'email_already_exits',
    '5005' : 'username_already_exits',
    '5006' : 'error_while_subscribing'
  };
  $rootScope.categoriesPromise =  myappnameService.getCategoriesWithSpots();

}])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

  // $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.icon(' myappname-nav-back');
  $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text('');//
  $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');

  $stateProvider
  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })


  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.search', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/search',
    views: {
      'tab-search': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.main', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/main',
    views: {
      'tab-search': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-main.html',
        controller :'SearchCtrl'
        }
      }
  })
   .state('tab.cat-details', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/cat-details/:id',
    views: {
      'tab-search': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/cat-details.html',
        controller :'CategoryCtrl'
        }
      }
  })
  .state('tab.favorite', {
       cache: false,
      url: '/favorite?loggedIn',
      views: {
        'tab-favorite': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-favorite.html',
          controller: 'FavoriteCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('tab.add', {
    url: '/add?loggedIn',
    views: {
      'tab-add': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-add.html',
        controller: 'AddCtrl'
      }
    }
  }).state('tab.settings', {
    url: '/settings?loggedIn',
    views: {
      'tab-settings': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-settings.html',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.favsubscribe', {
    url: '/favorite/subscribe',
    views: {
      'tab-favorite': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/subscribe.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.favlogin', {
    url: '/favorite/login',
    views: {
      'tab-favorite': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/main');

  $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');

    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
      search: "Search",
      favorite: "Favorite",
    });

    $translateProvider.translations('fr', {
      search: "Recherche",
      favorite: "Favoris",
    });


    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage("en");


});
```

my service.js :

```
angular.module('myappname.services', [])
.config(["$provide", function ($provide) {
    var URL = "http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/html/myappname/";
    $provide.value("apiRoot", URL + "Service.php");
}])
.service('myappnameService', function ($http,apiRoot,$q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var selectedCateogry = '';
    var searchTerm = '';

    this.getCategories = function(){
        $http.get(apiRoot+'?action=getCategories').then(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

And finally list of plugins used :

```
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
com.synconset.imagepicker 1.0.7 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.4.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-directions 0.4.3 "Directions"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.0.6 "SocialSharing"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File"
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.5.0 "File Transfer"
```

- I checked AndroidManifest and i have the INTERNET Permission

I'm using ionic to 1.7.8, cordova 5.4.0

Anything else i should do to make it work ?

Comment: have you tried `allow-intent`?

Comment: yes. to note this happened directly after i updated ionic to 1.7.8

Comment: Okay. You **may** need to make parts of your code public visible. Namely, config.xml and index.html (or equivalent), and maybe, maybe your main javascript library. Please respond, making sure to use my handle.

Comment: Thanks @JesseMonroy650, I updated my question above.

Comment: Are you using an SDK with an IDE (Eclipse, Andriod Studio, Visual Studio)? or CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite a few issues that are not obvious to the average developer. Mostly because it is easy to read something and not realize that it may not apply. However, the good news is that your code is cleaner than most people's code.

1. `<feature (...)>` does not apply to CLI. It is intended for SDK. See: [The config.xml File](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/config_ref/index.html), scroll down. Near the bottom it says:

   > *If you use the CLI to build applications (...) the  element does not apply to your workflow.*

   In short, that line is not doing anything - and certainly not what you intend it to do.
2. The `<platform (...)>` element does NOT apply to the `whitelist`. You will see it conspicuously missing from the [`whitelist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist) documentation. This is a common mistake. I'm not sure if it was in the `legacy-whitelist` or not; or just a leap of mistaken logic by the developers.

Move your whitelist stuff outside the `<platform (...)>` XML enclosure. It should not be a child of *platform*. FWIW: `whitelist` mostly applies to *Android* and by happenstance to the rest of the platforms.

3. If you need help applying the whitelist, here is a doc on that: 
   [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)
4. `<preference>, <feature> and <platform>` are confusing. Even though this is not finished, this document will help. [The `<preference>` mess](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/preference-mess.md).
5. You MUST wait to fire any code that touches the network or any of the mobile device services (especially those that Cordova controls) until after the `deviceready` event fires. This usually works, if you move all your JavaScript `<!-- your app's js -->` below your `</body>` tag.
6. This is another document that might help. [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: wow thannk you for the detailed review, this really gives me a head start on cordova, since i just got started

Comment: I made all the changes, and still have the issue.For the time being i donwgraded to 4.3.1

Comment: Yes, there are still a few bugs in the latest release of Cordova. See, if you can identify those bugs. Then I'll find those bugs in the bug repository so you can help vote those bugs up to be fixed. Best of Luck.